# CORS Server Configuration

Tags: javascript, c#, php, iis

I'm having a CORS issue hitting an API and trying to work out the issue with the API provider but it's a little over my head.

the get request I am sending using axios is

```
axios({
     method: 'post',
     url: <endpoint url>,
     data: someDataObj,
     headers: {
         'Authorization': <api key>,
         'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
     }
 })
```

The server is configured to allow

- headers: Authorization,Content-type
- methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS
- origin: *

The error in chrome is

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

and the network response is

```
GENERAL
Request URL: <api url>
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: 128.136.1.24:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

RESPONSE HEADERS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 30 Jan 2019 17:22:53 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

REQUESTHEADERS
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: <domain>
Referer: <page url>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

Everything seems to be configured right, but like I said I'm not super familiar with this stuff so maybe we're missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome thinks, that your request is not a [simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests) and does a [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) (OPTIONS instead of POST). This is because of your `Authorization` header and the value of your `Content-Type` header. Both require a preflighted (OPTIONS) request.

The server responds to the preflighted request, but he also sends the status code 500 (Internal Server Error) along with it, which should not happen. The status code should be 200 (OK). That's why Chrome denies the response to the OPTIONS request and never does the actual POST request. It's an server side issue.